# ASP.NET Core MVC identity - 3 users (admin, client, not logged in user). Set up controller only for client and not logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a shop app. There is a shopping cart option which is serviced by `ShoppingCartController`. I want all actions from this controller would be executed only if an user is not logged in or if is the client.

To be clear:

- Not logged in user - an user that has no role and is not logged in
- Client - an user that get "Client" role once he logs in and looses this role once he logs out. He does not have "Admin" role
- Admin - an user that has "Admin" role, no matter if is logged in or out.

So something like:

```
[Authorize(Roles != "Admin")]
public class ShoppingCartController : Controller {}
```

or

```
[Authorize(Roles = "NotLoggedInUser, Client")]
public class ShoppingCartController : Controller {}
```

Comment: The second approach should work for you, is there any issue when you try to implement it?

Comment: @JovanTopolac When user is not logged in, the User variable seems to be null: var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

Comment: you can use `[AllowAnonymous]` to allow access by non-authenticated users to individual actions